# ISAPI Block external access to folder / filetype

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, isapi

I have a website running on IIS - Is there a way to do the following using ISAPI Rewrite:

1) prevent external access to a folder on my site (ie request not from within the website - a user is trying to get into the folder via the address bar) - say http://www.example.com/folder1 but allow the website itself to pull elements from within the folder1 (images, flash files etc) without the same restrictions

Thanks...